# How to get data in regex in between multiple pair of indexes/positions

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to get chunk of data from sentence in between multiple pair of positions.

"There is forest and hills. That place is amazing"
out of this sentence I want data in between the indexes

1. 8 - 13 -> forest
2. 18 - 23 -> hills

so output will be -> **forest hills**

Comment: I will use a python script (or whatever langage you like) to do that, and invoke that script with ExecuteScript or ExecuteScriptCommand.

Comment: where those indexes are located? are they static? or coming with some attributes? how many of them?